# Creating a REST wrapper to an existing SOAP web service

Tags: .net, web-services

I have a .NET web service which is a SOAP service. I want to convert it into a REST service.

What options do I have to create that middle ware to:

- take request and make a call to soap service
- translate the result returned by SOAP service
- return response back to the requestor?

Answer (score 3):

You have two options

1) Just create a WCF service with two endpoints one with webhttpbinding and the other with basichttpbinding (i.e. soap). You don't need to relay calls from one service to another.

2) Wrap all your business logic in a class that is consumed by SOAP service class and your REST service class. You can write REST service using ASP.NET MVC or WCF.