# SOAP encoding in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, visual-studio, soap, windows-store-apps

I am trying to create a Windows Store App that consumes a web service. Visual Studio denies to create service proxy methods with following warning in logs:

> Custom tool warning: Contract ... is not compatible with Windows Store apps because it contains one or more operations with SOAP Encoding (use='encoded'). Only the non-encoded operations will be generated.

So the questions are:

Where can I find full list of Windows Store app limitations on web services consumption?
Are there any known workarounds (given I can't change the service)?

Comment: This might be helpfull for you to go through if you haven't already (Windows Store app fundamentals: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh750302.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're pretty much screwed if you can't change the web service because of the way that any wrappers are most likely SOAP encoded, and also the SOAP Toolkit doesn't allow for much output customisation.

Perhaps writing a (possibly functionally duplicated) web.api based webservice is a better solution? See [this link for an example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c25b6d/create-a-web-api-and-consume-it-in-the-windows-8-apps/)

EDIT: In response to the first comment...

Yes and no; essentially create a REST (whether that be webapi, WCF etc is upto you) wrapper.

See these informative posts on creating a REST wrapper:

[helpfull post number 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620706/creating-a-rest-wrapper-to-an-existing-soap-web-service) and [helpfull post number 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352998/building-rest-wrapper-over-an-existing-soap-web-service)

Comment: So, basically I should
1. Create and deploy a web app that "translates" third party SOAP to a WebAPI 
2. Consume resulting WebAPI in my Win8

Am I getting it right?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a NETStandard class library to reference the webservice, then reference this library to your web project.