# How to use SOAP method of a web service in UWP app?

Tags: c#, soap, win-universal-app, service-reference

I want to use a sms web service in UWP app for sending messeges, but when I add the address as a refrence, while it's showing me the methods, but can't use them. for example send method as you can see in the picture below:

[image]

This is my web service address:

http://smsg.ir/webservice/?wsdl

Comment: Is there some kind of authentication mechanism implemented for this webservice?

Comment: @Saadi when we want to use send method, we have to add user name and password as parameter. Do you think is that related to this status?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Its all depends on implementation of service

Comment: Perhaps, your username and password is not validation due to this it's not sending sms.

Comment: The warning message seems to be very clear: _Contract 'samWSDLPortType' is not compatible with Windows Store apps because it contains one or more operations with SOAP Encoding (use='encoded'). Only the non-encoded operations will be generated._.

Comment: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485561/soap-encoding-in-windows-store-app) may help you.

Comment: @jstreet thanks for your help.